# casting object to string[]

Tags: c#, string, return-value, return-type

The function fixOutput formats the data and outputs it after going through some regular expressions

```
static object fixOutput(string data)
    {
        string user = "Unknown";
        string message = "";
        string command = "";
        string[] args = {};
        string newdata = Regex.Replace(data, @"!.+ :", ":");
        Regex nameExpr = new Regex(@":.*:");
        Match match = nameExpr.Match(newdata);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            user = Regex.Replace(match.Groups[0].Value,":", "");
            //Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
        message = Regex.Replace(newdata, ":.*:", "");

        Regex ComExpr = new Regex(@"\!.*");
        match = ComExpr.Match(message);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            command = match.Groups[0].Value;
        }
        return new string[] { user, message, command };

    }
```

Yet, when i try to do this:

```
string[] returnValue = fixOutput(data);
```

It says:
    Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

I do not understand why i am getting this error as both (as far as i can see) are string[]

Here is some sample input data:

```
:minijack!minijack@minijack.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #minijack :hello Kappa
```

Comment: fixOutput returns an object. Change the method declaration to return a string[] if that's what you want.

Comment: Use `static string[] fixOutput(string data)` as your function signature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly cast your object to `string[]` or use [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator like:

```
string[] returnValue = fixOutput(data) as string[];
```

Or

```
string[] returnValue = string[](fixOutput(data));
```

But **more importantly** , why are you returning a string array inside an object ?. You can modify your method to return a string array or `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: I think `(string[])` would be better as it will throw an exception on failure. `as` would just silently fail if fixOutput didn't return a `string[]`.

Comment: @cdmckay, just added that as an option as well. :) But it really depends on situation, sometimes you don't want an exception to be raised, and instead you can compare if it is `null`, *(casting failed)*

Comment: Right, I just think a cast is better in most cases, as it fails right away instead of letting a null trickle down and potentially cause hard to trace problems elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Listen to the compiler message:

> It says: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string[]'. **An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).**

Try:

```
string[] returnValue = (string[]) fixOutput(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

When the object is declared, it says it is going to return an object, i changed it to:

```
static string[] fixOutput(string data)
```

which works, thanks for the help. It was a stupid mistake
Thanks cdmckay

Answer (score 0):

You can't *implicitly* cast from an `object` to a `string[]` - you can *explicitly* cast:

```
string[] returnValue = (string[])fixOutput(data);
```

or change the return type of the function to `string[]`

Answer (score 0):

Because in the method declaration you have specified that an `object` will be returned, you could really return just about anything from that method.

This is because all classes in C# derive from System.Object. However, when you return a `string[]` as an object, you then need to explicitly tell the compiler to cast it to a `string[]` if you want to use it as such.

```
string[] output = (string[])fixOutput(data);
```

However, as others have mentioned, it's really better to just return a `string[]` if you don't have a specific reason to return an `object`.